# Unnecessary effect have been found when creating GIF using array of UIImages

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-graphics, gif

I'm using following code to create GIF from array of UIImages.

```
func generateImagesToGif(photos: [UIImage], filename: String) -> Bool {
        let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let path = documentsDirectoryPath.appending(filename)
        let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]
        let gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.5]]
        let cfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL
        if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(cfURL, kUTTypeGIF, photos.count, nil) {
            CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)
            for photo in photos {
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, photo.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
            }
            return CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
        }
        return false
    }
```

But I've found an unexpected effect to GIF.
Here is my problem (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFnddM8CICjFkTKRbF8veDxF5R0lXSlV/view?usp=sharing) 
What's my mistake with this code? How to avoid any kind of effect? even I added original images to create GIF without resizing. But this effect always found.
How to solve? 
[image: Here is the unexpected problem I added]

Comment: A standard GIF is only 256 colors and that's likely why the natural sky gradient looks like this. You can double check that by converting the source jpg in any graphical program to GIF and the result should be the same.

Comment: Yup. But is there any way to improve? or any way which can contain more than 256 colors?